# How to implode these conditions to achieve this query structure?

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my working query that gets into action after a form submit. My query works only if all textboxes are filled, so currently everything is required.

**WORKING QUERY**

```
SELECT behaviour.hash, 
       Sum(behaviour.timespent) AS timeSpent, 
       new_table.percentile_rank, 
       Count(*) AS total 
FROM   behaviour, 
       audience, 
       new_table 
WHERE  ( $url ) 
       AND behaviour.timestamp >= Date_sub(Curdate(), INTERVAL $last_visit day) AND behaviour.timestamp < Date_add(Curdate(), INTERVAL 1 day) 
       AND behaviour.hash = audience.hash 
       AND behaviour.hash = new_table.hash 
       AND audience.country = '$from_country' 
GROUP  BY behaviour.hash 
HAVING Count(*) >= $more_than 
       AND timespent >= $time_spent 
       AND new_table.percentile_rank >= $lead_scoring
```

What I want to achieve is **not** to require the user to fill all the textboxes in order to submit, but only those he prefers. So I built the following, but it has some errors.

My problem is that my query has a `having` clause so not every `condition` is connected with `AND` as I have for now (look below my code). So, the first of the `$more_than` or `$time_spent` or `$lead_scoring` textboxes that submitted, it must have `HAVING` instead of `AND`.

How to edit my code in order to achieve this "special conditions" ?

**MY CODE**

```
$url= 'url="'.implode('" OR url="', $vals).'"';

$conditions = array();

if (!empty($last_visit)) $conditions[] = "behaviour.TIMESTAMP >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL '".$last_visit."' DAY) AND behaviour.TIMESTAMP < DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) ";
if (!empty($from_country)) $conditions[] = "audience.country = '".$from_country."'";
if (!empty($more_than)) $conditions[] = "COUNT( * ) >= '".$more_than."'"; 
if (!empty($time_spent)) $conditions[] = "timeSpent >= '".$time_spent."'";
if (!empty($lead_scoring)) $conditions[] = "new_table.percentile_rank >= '".$lead_scoring."'";


$conditionString = implode(' AND ', $conditions);


$sql = "SELECT behaviour.hash, 
       Sum(behaviour.timespent) AS timeSpent, 
       new_table.percentile_rank, 
       Count( * ) AS total 
FROM   behaviour, 
       audience, 
       new_table 
WHERE  ($url) AND ".$conditionString;
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

In the example below, all textboxes except `more_than` have been filled. The thing is that instead `AND timespent >= '20'` should be `HAVING timespent >= '20'`

```
SELECT behaviour.hash, 
       SUM(behaviour.timespent) AS timeSpent, 
       new_table.percentile_rank, 
       Count(*) AS total 
FROM   behaviour, 
       audience, 
       new_table 
WHERE  ( url = "/10369" ) 
       AND behaviour.timestamp >= Date_sub(Curdate(), interval '3' day) 
       AND behaviour.timestamp < Date_add(Curdate(), interval 1 day) 
       [missing]     AND behaviour.hash = audience.hash
       [missing]     AND behaviour.hash = new_table.hash
       AND audience.country = 'it' 
       [missing]     GROUP BY behaviour.hash
       [wrong]       AND timespent >= '20' ////// it should be HAVING /////
       AND new_table.percentile_rank >= '30'
```

Comment: I have updated my question adding some more output code

Comment: you have done with this  $conditionString = implode(' AND ', $conditions) that why it is  coming and

Comment: @krishnpatel yes, I understand this.

Comment: you should implement different logic for **having**

Comment: @krishnpatel yes, I know that. This is what is written in my question.

Comment: there is any having condition come every time ?

Comment: Conacatenating is easy. It would be enough to split your `$conditions` into `$where_conditions` and `$having_conditions`. But its not the only problem - the other one is **SQL injection**. You might consider using some query builder library which will handle that for you or build your own (but its more difficult than this concatenating).

Comment: two words: sql Injection. Al your datebases are belong to us. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Tschallacka I agree with you, but I will do the `escapes`

Comment: just use prepared statements. Don't escape stuff yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a bit "tricky" approach (looks clean though) that is using prepared statements. I've added some general purpose "features" in case of future changes.
Read the comments with explanations (will be more convenient this way I think):

```
//assume established PDO connection - example:
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname={$database_name};host=localhost", $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//static: conditional strings without parameters check (no keys required)
//conditional: assoc - keys should match both query placeholders and variable names
$static_where = [];
$optional_where = [
    'last_visit'   => 'behaviour.TIMESTAMP >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL :last_visit DAY) AND behaviour.TIMESTAMP < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)',
    'from_country' => 'audience.country = :from_country'
];

$static_having = [];
$optional_having = [
    'more_than'    => 'COUNT(*) >= :more_than',
    'time_spent'   => 'timeSpent >= :time_spent',
    'lead_scoring' => 'new_table.percentile_rank >= :lead_scoring'
];

//params: query parameters array - assigned manually + resolved from optional variables
$params = [];

//resolve condition from $urls array
if (count($urls) == 1) {
    $static_where[] = 'url = :url';
    $params['url'] = reset($urls);
} else if (!empty($urls)) {
    foreach ($urls as $idx => $url) {
        $params['url' . $idx] = $url;
    }
    $static_where[] = 'url IN(:' . implode(', :', array_keys($params)) . ')';
}

//filtering existing params used in query
//empty() is not a good idea for general purpose though,
//because some valid values might be recognised as empty (int 0, string '0')
$params += array_filter(
    compact(array_keys($optional_where), array_keys($optional_having)),
    function ($value) { return !empty($value); }
);

//concatenating conditional strings
//with corresponding params that weren't filtered out
//or these without params (static)
$where_clause = implode(' AND ', $static_where + array_intersect_key($optional_where, $params));
$having_clause = implode(' AND ', $static_having + array_intersect_key($optional_having, $params));

//don't need clauses without conditions - same as if (!empty($where)) {...}
empty($where_clause) or $where_clause = 'WHERE ' . $where_clause;
empty($having_clause) or $having_clause = 'HAVING ' . $having_clause;

$sql = "SELECT 
          behaviour.hash,
          Sum(behaviour.timespent) AS timeSpent,
          new_table.percentile_rank,
          Count( * ) AS total 
        FROM behaviour,
        INNER JOIN audience ON behaviour.hash = audience.hash,
        INNER JOIN new_table ON behaviour.hash = new_table.hash 
        {$where_clause}
        GROUP BY behaviour.hash 
        {$having_clause}";

//PDO part
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result = $query->execute($params);
//...
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. i will try it asap. Can you please tell me if it handles this? `$url= 'url="'.implode('" OR url="', $vals).'"';`

Comment: @Pashiamas Not yet. Need to think on this - I'll let you know when sth comes up.

Comment: @Pashiamas Added `$urls` array case - using `IN()` clause instead of `OR`s (faster). It looks more like a hack, but its time to envolve this code into some organised library object(s).

Comment: Hi shudder. I tested the logic for the "non requiring" part and it works fine. However I am having difficulties to make it work with the `$urls`. This is the code I use `$urls = array($_POST['future_visited_page']);` that outputs if i `print_r($urls)` this `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => /results.php [1] => /contact.php ) )`. Of course it depends on the how many `urls` will be selected.

Comment: @Pashiamas assign directly `$urls = $_POST['future_visited_page']`. It should be one dimensional array (or empty array if nothing passed).

Comment: shudder thank you for this. Now I can not print any results.. this is the code I am using `while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo 'this and that';
}` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Pashiamas It's `$result->fetch()`

Comment: I tried it with `result` but I get `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on boolean` even without `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Comment: @Pashiamas Oh sorry, you're right. To see what went wrong check produced query, it it's ok then do some [error inspection](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php). Maybe there's no matching rows (wrong query logic or simply no data).

Comment: I tried everything, unfortunately I always get `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on boolean`. I checked the produced query directly in phpmyadmin and I get the results...

Comment: @Pashiamas If you use `fetch()` on `$query` as you said earlier then it's correct. This error means that thare was an error - read linked manual.

Comment: Everything works fine except one thing. If the chosn `url` is only 1 then somehow the query returns always zero. However, if i select `url` the query works fine. I have tested it through phpmyadmin and it seems something is wrong on the `url` part of he code.

Comment: Basically my version allows me to handle my queries better because `$url= 'url="'.implode('" OR url="', $vals).'"';` allows me to change the `or` to `and` if I may...

Comment: @Pashiamas It should work If you always pass `$urls` as an array (zero, one or more string elements). You won't need to change `or` to `and` because one field cannot be equal to many values at the same time.

Comment: This is what I do `$urls = $_POST['future_visited_page'];` and then follows your code. If I echo the `$_post` gives either `url1` for 1 url or `url1,url2,url3` for many

Comment: @Pashiamas There was a typo in `reset($url);` line - changed to `reset($urls);`. Think I've corrected it in my test file after code was pasted here:/

Answer (score 10):

First, you **must** ensure SQL injection is not possible. To do that, lets use PDO.

Next, to solve your actual problem, you simple need to create two lists with conditions. One with the conditions you want to have in the `WHERE` part of the query, and one with the conditions that need to go in the `HAVING` part of the query.

```
    $pdo = new PDO(/* See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php */);

    $whereConditions = [];
    $havingConditions = [];
    $parameters = [];

    if (!empty($last_visit)) {
        $whereConditions[] = "behaviour.TIMESTAMP >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL :last_visit DAY) AND behaviour.TIMESTAMP < DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) ";
        $parameters['last_visit'] = $last_visit;
    }
    if (!empty($from_country)) {
        $whereConditions[] = "audience.country = :from_country";
        $parameters['from_country'] = $from_country;
    }
    if (!empty($more_than)) {
        $havingConditions[] = "COUNT( * ) >= :more_than";
        $parameters['more_than'] = $more_than;
    }
    if (!empty($time_spent)) {
        $havingConditions[] = "timeSpent >= :time_spent";
        $parameters['time_spent'] = $time_spent;

    }
    if (!empty($lead_scoring)) {
        $havingConditions[] = "new_table.percentile_rank >= :lead_scoring";
        $parameters['lead_scoring'] = $lead_scoring;
    }

    if (count($vals)) {
        $escapedUrlList = implode(', ', array_map(function ($url) use ($pdo) {
            return $pdo->quote($url);
        }, $vals));
        $whereConditions[] = "url IN($escapedUrlList)";
    }

    $whereClause = count($whereConditions) ? ' AND ' . implode(' AND ', $whereConditions) : '';
    $havingClause = count($havingConditions) ? ' HAVING ' . implode(' AND ', $havingConditions) : '';

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("
        SELECT behaviour.hash, 
            Sum(behaviour.timespent) AS timeSpent, 
            new_table.percentile_rank, 
            Count(*) AS total 
        FROM behaviour, 
            audience, 
            new_table 
        WHERE behaviour.hash = audience.hash 
            AND behaviour.hash = new_table.hash 
            {$whereClause}
        GROUP  BY behaviour.hash
        {$havingClause}
    ");

    $result = $statement->execute($parameters);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. through my error_log I found this entry `DB:SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Comment: One thing that slip my mind is this line `$url= 'url="'.implode('" OR url="', $vals).'"';` because it can choose multiple urls from a selectbox

Comment: Bound -- You must use the escape routine for each variable -- instead of using "bind".

Comment: @Pashiamas I've fixed the error and now support the `$vals` variable (which you may want to rename to `$urls` or `$selectedUrlList` or something like that, because `$vals` doesn't really describe what it's for).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a less complicated way using string concatenation instead of `implode`. The "trick" is to start the conditions with `1=1`. So every following condition can begin with `AND`.

```php
$andWhere  = '';
$andHaving = '';
$params = [];


if (!empty($last_visit)) {
    $andWhere .= " AND behaviour.TIMESTAMP >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL :last_visit DAY AND behaviour.TIMESTAMP < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY";
    $params['last_visit'] = $last_visit;
}
if (!empty($from_country)) {
    $andWhere .= " AND audience.country = :from_country";
    $params['from_country'] = $from_country;
}
if (!empty($more_than)) {
    $andHaving .= " AND COUNT( * ) >= :more_than";
    $params['more_than'] = $more_than;
}
if (!empty($time_spent)) {
    $andHaving .= " AND timeSpent >= :time_spent";
    $params['time_spent'] = $time_spent;
}
if (!empty($lead_scoring)) {
    $andHaving .= " AND new_table.percentile_rank >= :lead_scoring";
    $params['lead_scoring'] = $lead_scoring;
}

$urlPlaceholders = [];
foreach ($vals as $key => $val) {
    $urlPlaceholders[] = ":url_$key";
    $params["url_$key"] = $val;
}
if (count($vals) > 0) {
    $inUrl = implode(',', $urlPlaceholders);
    $andWhere .= " AND url IN ($inUrl)";
}

$sql = "
    SELECT behaviour.hash, 
           Sum(behaviour.timespent) AS timeSpent, 
           new_table.percentile_rank, 
           Count(*) AS total 
    FROM   behaviour 
    JOIN   audience  ON behaviour.hash = audience.hash
    JOIN   new_table ON behaviour.hash = new_table.hash
    WHERE  1=1 {$andWhere}
    GROUP  BY behaviour.hash 
    HAVING 1=1 {$andHaving}
";

#var_export($sql);
#var_export($params);

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($params);
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

#var_export($data);
```

Having sample data like

```php
$last_visit   = '';
$from_country = 'UK';
$more_than    = '5';
$time_spent   = '3';
$lead_scoring = '';
$vals = ['u1', 'u2'];
```

You would get the following query:

```sql
SELECT behaviour.hash, 
       Sum(behaviour.timespent) AS timeSpent, 
       new_table.percentile_rank, 
       Count(*) AS total 
FROM   behaviour 
JOIN   audience  ON behaviour.hash = audience.hash
JOIN   new_table ON behaviour.hash = new_table.hash
WHERE  1=1  AND audience.country = :from_country AND url IN (:url_0,:url_1)
GROUP  BY behaviour.hash 
HAVING 1=1  AND COUNT(*) >= :more_than AND timeSpent >= :time_spent
```

with these bindings:

```php
array (
  'from_country' => 'UK',
  'more_than' => '5',
  'time_spent' => '3',
  'url_0' => 'u1',
  'url_1' => 'u2',
)
```

[**Demo on rextester.com**](http://rextester.com/VBK95059)

Comment: BTW: Your query is probably wrong because `new_table.percentile_rank` is not in the `GROUP BY` clause - so it doesn't make sense as it is. You might want to use `MAX(new_table.percentile_rank)`  instead. But i let it as it is because it's not part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

If having is the only problem why not splitting it into different block like this:

```
$conditions = array();

if (!empty($last_visit)) $conditions[] = "behaviour.TIMESTAMP >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL '".$last_visit."' DAY) AND behaviour.TIMESTAMP < DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) ";
if (!empty($from_country)) $conditions[] = "audience.country = '".$from_country."'";


$conditionString = implode(' AND ', $conditions);

$conditions_having = array();
if (!empty($more_than)) $conditions_having[] = "COUNT( * ) >= '".$more_than."'"; 
if (!empty($time_spent)) $conditions_having[] = "timeSpent >= '".$time_spent."'";
if (!empty($lead_scoring)) $conditions_having[] = "new_table.percentile_rank >= '".$lead_scoring."'";

$conditionString .= " GROUP  BY behaviour.hash" 
if(count($conditions_having))
$conditionString .= " HAVING ".implode(' AND ', $conditions_having); 

$sql = "SELECT behaviour.hash, 
       Sum(behaviour.timespent) AS timeSpent, 
       new_table.percentile_rank, 
       Count( * ) AS total 
FROM   behaviour, 
       audience, 
       new_table 
WHERE  ($url) AND ".$conditionString;
```

Comment: `lead_scoring` should fall below `having`. I think that with yout proposal it falls above `having` which is incorrect. Also, what happens if none of `lead_scoring`, `more_than`, `time_spent` is filled?

Comment: yes you are right. I have fixed those conditions. @Pashiamas

Answer (score 2):

You can change only your implode function to this code

```
$conditionString = implode(' ', array_map(function($item) {
if ((strpos($item, 'timeSpent') !== false))
    return 'HAVING '.$item;
return 'AND '.$item;
}, $conditions));
```

**Be aware that your code is vulnerable.**

for more information see this: [SQL Injection In CAPEC](https://capec.mitre.org/data/definitions/66.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
  $url= 'url="'.implode('" OR url="', $vals).'"';

  $conditions = array();
  $havings = array();

    if (!empty($last_visit)) $conditions[] = "behaviour.TIMESTAMP >= DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL '".$last_visit."' DAY) AND behaviour.TIMESTAMP < DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) ";
    if (!empty($from_country)) $conditions[] = "audience.country = '".$from_country."'";
    if (!empty($more_than)) $havings[] = "COUNT( * ) >= '".$more_than."'"; 
    if (!empty($time_spent)) $havings[] = "timeSpent >= '".$time_spent."'";
    if (!empty($lead_scoring)) $havings[] = "new_table.percentile_rank >= '".$lead_scoring."'";


    $conditionString = implode(' AND ', $conditions);

    $havingString = '';
    if(count($havings)>0) {
         $havingString = ' having '.implode(', ', $havings);    
    }

    $sql = "SELECT behaviour.hash, 
           Sum(behaviour.timespent) AS timeSpent, 
           new_table.percentile_rank, 
           Count( * ) AS total 
    FROM   behaviour, 
           audience, 
           new_table 
    WHERE  ($url) AND ".$conditionString.$havingString;
```